# Unity3d c#. onClick.AddListener() works once

Tags: c#, button, canvas, unity-game-engine

There's a void in the script, which reloads Canvas. The Canvas contains the Button object. I attach the reload void with the script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Trashscript : MonoBehaviour {

   public GameObject Temp;
   private GameObject Active;
   int Counter;

   void Start()
   {
       Menu();
   }

  void Menu()
   {
       Counter++;

       if (Active != null) Destroy(Active);
       Active = Instantiate(Temp);

       GameObject.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>().text = Counter.ToString();
       GameObject.Find("Btn").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(Menu);
   }
}
```

First call (from `Start`) works fine the "Text" element shows "1". After clicking the "Btn" Canvas reloads, but there isn't any "Text", and "Btn" doesn't work (onClick event do nothing).

Help.

Comment: i dont know unity but it could be because your Menu() is readding the event to itself. try adding the listener only one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with changing the `GameObject.Find("")` to `Active.transform.Find("")`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell what your code is doing but each time the `Button` is clicked, `Menu` function is called which leads to `GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(Menu)` being called again.

You have to move `GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(Menu)` out of the `Munu` function and into the `Start()` function. You also have to un-register to the `Button` event in the `OnDisable()` function.

Below is what your code should look like:

```
Button button;

void Start()
{
    button = GameObject.Find("Btn").GetComponent<Button>();
    button.onClick.AddListener(Menu);
}

void OnDisable()
{
    button.onClick.RemoveListener(Menu);
}

void Menu()
{
    ///Put Your Button click code here

}
```

Comment: Understood, but i need to recreate "Menu" object each click on button.